# resize image with bilinear interpolation in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, python-imaging-library, resize-image

I want to resize image with bilinear interpolation. I found new intensity value but I do not know how can I use it.. The code is below which is I written..

```
def resizeImageBI(im,width,height):
    temp = np.zeros((height,width),dtype=np.uint8)
    ratio_1 = float(im.size[0] - 1 )/ float(width - 1)
    ratio_0 = float(im.size[1] - 1) / float(height - 1)
    xx,yy = np.mgrid[:height, :width]
    xmap = np.around(xx * ratio_0)
    ymap = np.around(yy * ratio_1)

for i in xrange(0, height):
    for j in xrange(0,width):
        temp[i][j]=im.getpixel( ( ymap[i][j], xmap[i][j]) ) * getNewIntensity(i,j,ratio_1,ratio_0)

return Image.fromarray(temp)
```

firstly get variable image width ratio and height ratio

```
lena.png 0.5 1
```

[Orginal image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNTJl.png)

[That is output accorting to written code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTz6P.png)

Answer (score 1):

I just had to do this for a class and I haven't been graded yet, so you should check this out before using.

#### Basic Interpolation function

```
def interpolation(y0,x0, y1,x1, x):
    frac = (x - x0) / (x1 - x0)
    return y0*(1-frac) + y1 * frac
```

#### Step 1: Map the original coordinates to the newly resized image

```
def get_coords(im, W, H):
    h,w = im.shape
    x = np.arange(0,w+1,1) * W/w 
    y = np.arange(0,h+1,1) * H/h 
    return x,y
```

#### Step 2: Create a function to interpolate in the x-direction on all rows.

```
def im_interp(im, H,W):
    X = np.zeros(shape=(W,H))
    x, y = get_coords(im, W, H)
    for i,v in enumerate(X):
        y0_idx = np.argmax(y >i) - 1
        for j,_ in enumerate(v):
            # subtracting 1 because this is the first val
            # that is greater than j, want the idx before that
            x0_idx = np.argmax(x > j) - 1
            x1_idx = np.argmax(j < x) 

            x0 = x[x0_idx]
            x1 = x[x1_idx]

            y0 = im[y0_idx, x0_idx - 1]
            y1 = im[y0_idx, x1_idx - 1]

            X[i,j] = interpolation(y0, x0, y1, x1, j)
    return X
```

#### Step 3: Use function from the above step to interpolate twice.  First on the image in the x-direction, then on the transpose of the newly created image (y-direction)

```
def im_resize(im,H,W):
    X_lin = im_interp(im, H,W)
    X = im_interp(X_lin.T, H,W)
    return X_lin, X.T
```

I return both images just to look at the difference.

Answer (score -2):

i'm not sure if you want to do this manually as an exercise...

if not, there is [scipy.mics.imresize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html) that can do what you want

Comment: i know there is a function for this but as you say trying for exercise